# Repeated random drawing with extra random variable

Tags: probability

While running a simulation on my computer I came into a probability question which I don't seem to be able to solve:

Let's say there is a bag with 5 distinct objects in it. I throw a five-sided die with the number 1-5 on it and then I take that amount of objects from the bag (with equal probability) after which all items are returned and you start over. In the end what is the long-term probability that an item is removed from the bag?

While simulating, I found that this is $0.6$, but how can I proof it?
I started by calculating the opposite probability, so that the object is NOT taken out. For 1 item $p(X=1)=\frac{1*4}{5*5}$ Since there is a $\frac{1}{5}$ chance that you throw 1 and the probability the item is not chosen is $\frac{4}{5}$. Similarly we get $p(X=2)=\frac{1*4*3}{5*5*5}$, $p(X=3)=\frac{1*4*3*2}{5*5*5*5}$, $p(X=4)=\frac{1*4*3*2*1}{5*5*5*5*5}$, $p(X=5)=0$ since you take all objects. Summing this up leaves us with $0.30208$ so the probability you get an item is around $0.7$ which is not the same as the $0.6$ from my simulation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_i$ be the event that object $i$ is removed and $D$ represent a dice. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}(R_i\mid D=d)=\frac{d}{5}
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{P}(R_i)=\sum_{d=1}^5 \mathsf{P}(R_i\mid D=d)\mathsf{P}(D=d)=\sum_{d=1}^5 \frac{d}{5}\times\frac{1}{5}=\frac{3}{5}=0.6
$$

Comment: Aah ok, so what I did wrong was by stating that the probability of being removed also depended on the position in the sample which is irrelevant here right?